# PHP table from JSON without names in array

Tags: php, json

I am having a problem with api Yandex.
I have to get data from api and make with php the table:

```
Source    Users   New    Pages   Bounce  Goal1  Goal2
organic   s1v1    s1v2   s1v3    s1v4    s1v5   s1v6
referral  s2v1    s2v2   s2v3    s2v4    s2v5   s2v6
(none)    s3v1    s3v2   s3v3    s3v4    s3v5   s3v6
```

After json_decode I have:

```
{"data":[
{"dimensions":[{"name":"organic"}],"metrics":[s1v1,s1v2,s1v3,s1v4,s1v5,s1v6]},
{"dimensions":[{"name":"referral"}],"metrics":[s2v1,s2v2,s2v3,s2v4,s2v5,s2v6]},
{"dimensions":[{"name":"(none)"}],"metrics":[s3v1,s3v2,s3v3,s3v4,s3v5,s3v6]},
]}
```

But I can't correctly parse it into a table. So far I have written code only for the first column Source, and then stuck:

```
<?php 
$metrika_o = json_decode($metrika);
echo "<table>
           <tr>
                <td><strong>Source</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Users</strong></td>
                <td><strong>New</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Pages</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Bounce</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Goal1</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Goal2</strong></td>
            </tr>";
foreach($metrika_o->data as $data)
foreach($data->dimensions as $source)
:
?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $source->name?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;
      echo "</table>";
?>
```

The Source number is constantly changing, the set of columns is fixed.
Please help me to solve this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right way:

```
<?php foreach($metrika_o->data as $data): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $data->dimensions[0]->name; ?></td>
    <?php foreach(explode(',',$data->metrics) as $col):
    <td><?php echo $col; ?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```